# Why are these arrows not plotting?

Tags: plotting, homework

I'm very new to mathematica, so pardon me for such a simple question.
I have tried to follow the syntax of the "Arrow" documentation(https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Arrow.html), but I cannot seem to add arrows to this Parametric Plot. I have no issue plotting a point to the plot (the red dot), but the arrows will not add. Can you spot the problem? Thank you for your time.

```
x = {4*Cos[s/5], 4*Sin[s/5], 3*s/5}  
pointOfInterest = {0, 4, 3*Pi/2};  
tangentv = pointOfInterest + {-4/5, 0, 3/5};  
normalv = pointOfInterest + {0, -1, 0};  
binormalv = pointOfInterest + {3/5, 0, 4/5};  
Show[  
 (*Sorting the curve itself and orientation.*)  
 ParametricPlot3D[{{x}},  
   {s, 0, 10}] /.   
  Line[x_] :> {Arrowheads[Table[.05, {5}]], Arrow[x]},  
 (*Adding the point, and corresponding vectors.*)  
 Graphics3D[{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{pointOfInterest}]}],  
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[Line[{{pointOfInterest}, {tangentv}}]]}],  
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[Line[{{pointOfInterest}, {normalv}}]]}],  
 Graphics3D[{Arrow[Line[{{pointOfInterest}, {binormalv}}]]}]]
```

[image]

Thanks very much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the  braces around `pointOfInterest`, `tangentv`, `normalv` and `binormalv`,that is, use `Graphics3D[{Arrow[Line[{pointOfInterest, tangentv}]]}]` instead of `Graphics3D[{Arrow[Line[{{pointOfInterest}, {tangentv}}]]}]`, similarly for other arrows to get:

[image]

A more compact way to get the same result is:

```
Show[ParametricPlot3D[{{x}}, {s, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Arrowheads[Table[.05, {5}]]] /. 
   Line -> Arrow, 
 Graphics3D[{{Red, PointSize[0.04], Point[{pointOfInterest}]}, 
   Black, Arrow[{pointOfInterest, #} & /@ {tangentv, normalv, binormalv}]}]]
```

> same picture

Comment: Thanks very much, your way is much clearer!

Comment: @MichaelMitchell, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept. And welcome to mma.se.